# Perturbative Solution to Boundary-layers Problem

Tags: perturbation-theory

Could anyone help me with the part marked in red? Why do we have a series expansion in there? And why does the limit epsilon -> 0 gives eq_in = Y''(w)+Y'(w)=0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this should be a comment but what is wrong with multiplying through by $\epsilon$ and then taking the limit?

Comment: are you referring to the second output marked in red?

Comment: Either will do. You then have a term with no $\epsilon$ and a term with $\epsilon$.

Comment: Okay it's a bit clearer now. But I'm not very familiar with that big-O notation. What happens when you multiply ϵ to it.

Also why do we do series expansion in the first place?

Comment: $\epsilon \times O(\epsilon)$ is $O(\epsilon^2)$

Comment: I see. Thanks!
_

Comment: One more question: when we multiply ϵ through, we will have the term ϵ(Y[w] + Y'[w]). How do you deal with it?